# Code block repeating when I want to implement try and catch exception

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm writing a C# console application where you enter your name and birthdate in yyyy/mm/dd format to have the console tell you your age  in years and months. Now I've got that part figured out and it works. Until I tried to also implement a try and catch exception to check if the date you entered was in the right format. If not it should tell you to try again 3 times before telling you the date format is incorrect and then quitting the app.

Now the problem is the app works sort of, but it tells you the date format is incorrect even when it isn't. Then still continues to give the correct output after looping through the app that asks for name and date of birth 3 times. This is the code I have so far(I know the year month output is a bit messy I just spent way too long testing too much stuff to try and change it now, I am open to improvements and changes though):

```
namespace CSConsoleDateTimeTypes
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Count = 0;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { EnterDate(); }
        static void EnterDate()
        {

            string userName, enteredDoBString;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your name:");
            userName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your date of birth in the format yyyy/mm/dd:");
            enteredDoBString = Console.ReadLine();
            string dateString = Console.ReadLine();
            parseDateString(dateString);
            DateTime enteredDoB = DateTime.Parse(enteredDoBString);
            Console.WriteLine("Your DoB is: {0}", enteredDoB);
            DateTime dateToday = DateTime.Today;
            if (dateToday < enteredDoB)
            {
                DateTime date4 = dateToday;
                dateToday = enteredDoB;
                enteredDoB = date4;
            }
            TimeSpan ts = dateToday - enteredDoB;
            //total days (irrelevant to the application though)
            Console.WriteLine(ts.TotalDays);
            //total years
            int years = dateToday.Year - enteredDoB.Year;

            int months = 0;
            //Total months
            if (dateToday.Month < enteredDoB.Month)
            {
                months = 12 - dateToday.Month + enteredDoB.Month;
            }
            else
            {
                months = enteredDoB.Month - dateToday.Month;

            }
            if (months > 12)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Years: {0}, Months: {1}", years - 1, 12 - (months - 12));
            }
            else if (months < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Years: {0}, Months: {1}", years, months - months);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Years: {0}, Months: {1}", years, months);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static void parseDateString(string datestring)
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime date3 = DateTime.Parse(datestring, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                date3.ToShortDateString();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                //if date was entered incorrectly 3 times, the application should exit..
                Count++;
                if (Count < 3)
                {
                    EnterDate();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\aSorry date still not in correct format - Press any key to exit the application");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output it gives when I launch the app and it finishes running through all the code after my inputs:

```
Enter your name:
gerrit
Enter your date of birth in the format yyyy/mm/dd:
1997/02/13

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
Enter your name:
gerrit
Enter your date of birth in the format yyyy/mm/dd:
1997/02/13

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
Enter your name:
gerrit
Enter your date of birth in the format yyyy/mm/dd:
1997/02/13

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
Sorry date still not in correct format - Press any key to exit the application
Your DoB is: 1997/02/13 12:00:00 AM
7294
Years: 20, Months: 0
Your DoB is: 1997/02/13 12:00:00 AM
7294
Years: 20, Months: 0
Your DoB is: 1997/02/13 12:00:00 AM
7294
Years: 20, Months: 0
```

As you can see it asks for name and date of birth 3 times and still telling me date format is incorrect then it gives the correct output (Your DoB is: 1997/02/13 12:00:00 AM
7294
Years: 20, Months: 0) 3 times

It should ask once and output once but I can't figure out how to do it. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here is a screenshot of the console output if it helps at all

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8RA0.png

Comment: The problem is that you are checking `dateString` instead of `enteredDoBString` and then eventually using `enteredDoBstring`. Delete `dateString` and pass `enteredDoBstring` to the method.

Comment: Why do you have two lines of code for the entered date string, namely `enteredDoBString and `dateString`?

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata and awh112 Thanks guys after I did that it works perfect now. Appreciate the help. Can't believe I didn't see that haha I'm still new and learning C#.

Answer (score 0):

I changed a little your code.

I don't have checked the rest of your code, only to ask the date.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
  EnterDate(); 
}

private static void EnterDate()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Enter your name:");
  var userName = Console.ReadLine();

  // ask for date
  var enteredDoBString = AskForDate();
  if (enteredDoBString == null)
    return;

  DateTime enteredDoB = DateTime.Parse(enteredDoBString);
  Console.WriteLine($"Your DoB is: {enteredDoB}");

  DateTime dateToday = DateTime.Today;

  if (dateToday < enteredDoB)
  {
    DateTime date4 = dateToday;
    dateToday = enteredDoB;
    enteredDoB = date4;
  }
  TimeSpan ts = dateToday - enteredDoB;

  // total days (irrelevant to the application though)
  Console.WriteLine(ts.TotalDays);

  // total years
  var years = dateToday.Year - enteredDoB.Year;
  var months = 0;         

  // Total months
  if (dateToday.Month < enteredDoB.Month)
  {
    months = 12 - dateToday.Month + enteredDoB.Month;
  }
  else
  {
    months = enteredDoB.Month - dateToday.Month;
  }

  if (months > 12)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"Years: {years - 1}, Months: {12 - (months - 12)}");
  }

  else if (months < 0)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"Years: {years}, Months: {months - months}");
  }

  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"Years: {years}, Months: {months}");
  }

  Console.ReadKey();
  Console.ReadKey();
}

private static string AskForDate()
{
  var count = 0;
  while (count++ < 3)
  {
    try
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Enter your date of birth in the format yyyy/mm/dd:");
      return DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToShortDateString();
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
      //if date was entered incorrectly 3 times, the application should exit..
    }
  }

  Console.WriteLine("\aSorry date still not in correct format - Press any key to exit the application");
  Console.ReadKey();

  return null;
}
```

What I made:

I removed your function `parseDateString` and create a new called `AskForDate`. This function, like the name says, ask for the date to the user, and inside this function, the date entered is checked if is valid or not. 
I believe that is better to check and ask on same function.
If the date entered by user is correct, the date is returned as `ToShortDateString`. If the date is incorrectly, the function ask two more times, and on third time, a `null` is returned.

Then, in the `EnterDate` function, if `null` is returned from `AskForDate` function, the program exits.

I also changed some strings interpolations, and removed some variables.